# Rediecting to another view from one view in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to create a reference (href) to direct my webpage from  one view to other view over a click:

my code is

- My controller ,test_cont has a function

  ```
  public function display(){   
     $this->load->view('test_view2');
  }
  ```

  -In  my  view I have tried b/m codes:

  1. ```
     $this->load->helper('url');
     <a href="<?php echo site_url('index.php/Test_cont/display');?>">Display View 2</a>
     ```
  2. ```
     $this->load->helper('url');
     <a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/Test_cont/display');?>">Display View 2</a>
     ```
  3. ```
     $this->load->helper('url');
     <a href="Test_cont/display">Display View 2</a>
     ```

and in all cases when i click on my the link *Display View 2* I get error 404. I have tried defining base_url too

Comment: best way to do this is `<a href="<?php echo site_url('Test_cont/display');?>">Display View 2</a>` because it will run in dev & production server without changing anything

Answer (score 0):

use like this and check it..

```
 echo base_url('Test_cont/display');
```